# How to set height of Barplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I try to set the height of a result of one barplot.

Can someone help me ?

Actually, I have this result ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. This entirely depends on what visualization library you're using. And we need to see your input data structures as well. Also, do you mean the height of the entire figure or the height of each bar?

Comment: Please type the code from your image out in your question so that it is searchable and copyable. You can edit your question to add this code in.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `subplots` function from `matplotlib` to control figure size. With seaborn you can often pass in a matplotlib axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

height = 20
width = 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(height,width)) # I might have swapped height and width here, I never remeber which order they're in

# Do what you had before with barplot just pass in your axis as the ax key word:
sns.barplot(..., ax=ax)
```